# Add parameters to query string in Swashbuckle paths

Tags: api, asp.net-core, .net-core, swagger, swashbuckle

I've got this controller with 2 actions, both GETs, the same name.

```
[ApiVersion("2")]
[Route("v{version:apiVersion}/[controller]")]
public class FooController : BaseController
```

And the two actions are like:

```
public IActionResult Get([FromServices]IBarService barService)  
public IActionResult Get([FromServices]IBarService barService, string someParameter)
```

But I do need **to distinguish those two actions as different operations** with **inputs** and even **outputs**. 
**Also I cannot change the behaviour of the current API**, it means, the final user should have access to the following listed paths:

```
GET v2/Foo
GET v2/Foo?someParameter={someParameter}
```

In the first place I had to add this line to make it work:

```
o.ResolveConflictingActions((apiDescriptions) => apiDescriptions.First());
```

It works, but when the OpenApiOperation are listed it had only the first one (for obvious reasons)

How can I add the query string parameters to make them work like 2 different paths?

Answer (score 0):

Here is an alternative:

```
[RoutePrefix("foo/widgets")]
public class RoutePrefixController : ApiController
{
    [Route("")]
    public string Get()
    {
        return "value";
    }

    [Route("{id}")]
    public string GetById(string id)
    {
        return "value " + id;
    }

    [Route("{id}/{name}")]
    public string GetByIdByName(string id, string name)
    {
        return "value " + id + " " + name;
    }
```

That uses `RoutePrefix` and `Route` your final enpoints are:

- `GET ​/foo​/widgets`
- `GET ​/foo​/widgets​/{id}`
- `GET ​/foo​/widgets​/{id}​/{name}`

Here is how that looks like on swagger:
http://swagger-net-test.azurewebsites.net/swagger/ui/index?filter=RoutePrefix